# HTML <img> (or JS image) versus inline images via PHP (base64_encoded image)

Tags: php, javascript, html, image

My web page initially populated around 1000 thumbnails by dynamically creating images in javascript. Due to permission issues, I migrated to suPHP. Now instead of using the standard `<img>` tags as such

```
<img src="/foo/bar.jpg" alt="Foo Bar"/>
```

I am retrieving via this php script

```
$file = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

$a = array(
    'type' => 'image/jpeg;base64',
    'image' => base64_encode($file)
);

echo json_encode($a);
```

And then creating the image like so (inside the xmlhttprequest call back, where image has been created already)

```
image.src = 'data:' + data['type'] + ',' + data['image'];
```

It work, but I can only reliably load half the pictures. If I try to load all of them, chrome crashes. I don't think this is performance related as the pictures load very quickly. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What happens in other browsers? It might be just a chrome bug.

Comment: its my opinion.
better you can load the images by URL http://website/image_file_name.

Comment: @Lyth firefox loads it but it is extremely slow. I think it might be b/c 1000 xmlhttprequests are too many to handle at once. I will try to put them in a sliding widnow

Comment: @balaphp is that link supposed to point nowhere? And I am using suPHP so files can't have the `0777` permissions apache needs.

Comment: Apparently the major advantage of base64 is that you can get all images in one request. I can't tell you exactly how it works (perhaps someone else can), but base64 might just solve your problem there.

Comment: no no i just mentioned you dont you try load the images by url..

Comment: @balaphp I see now. However, loading them by name is not an option (they are hidden and restricted)

Comment: @kasimir from what i have read, base64 merely converts binary data into a format which is safe for, for example, JSON. It actually makes files 30% bigger. I have never heard of getting all images in one request, although I can see how it can be done.

Comment: As far as I know the browser will not cache results from an XmlHttpRequest, so one disadvantage to this method is the additional burden on your server / bandwidth.

Comment: @nickb yes one of the costs of doing this yourself is you don't get such perks. Unfortunately, there is no way around this one.

Comment: @puk - Just curious, is it possible to change your PHP script to output a base64_encoded image (with appropriate headers), instead of using AJAX / JSON to return the image?

Comment: @nickb yes i can change my PHP script. I feel you are on the verge of making my life easier.

Comment: @puk I wonder if the reason you are having a problem is that the PHP script sometimes triggers an error, which makes the image data invalid? Have you loaded the result of the PHP script directly in a browser for the failed images to ensure it outputs JSON and *only* JSON?

Comment: @nickb it's not an error, the browser crashes. I just implemented a sliding window and it works better now.

Comment: @puk Maybe I'm missing something - Why do you have to use base64 encoding?

Comment: @puk this might be an interesting read: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to. This describes the differences. I now get the 'one request bit' which I have seen mentioned a time ago, it basically means stuffing your images in your css. Indeed, the total amount of data is bigger, 30% as you pointed out, so that's quite a disadvantage if you're talking about 1000 images. Also, stuffing your css with 1000 images seems like a bad idea as well.

Comment: @nickb images are in binary and apparently JSON is not good with binary, so you have to convert it. I am using base64_encode based off of examples.

Comment: @nickb thanks for the link, I'll have a look at it

Comment: @puk Those posts were from kasimir and DaveRandom :) I've posted an answer, I'm not sure if it's a possibility with your configuration / setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can call a PHP script to generate base64_encoded images, then you should(?) be able to let the browser load your images from a PHP script and skip JSON / AJAX altogether.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png'); // Change MIME type for different images (JPEG / GIF)
// Probably need Content-Length header in here too
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filename));

echo file_get_contents( $filename);
exit;
?>
```

Then use something like this (I used `image_id` to determine which image to load, you must have something similar):

```
<img src="/load_image.php?image_id=1234" alt="" />
```

Comment: Also, in case anyone is wondering, this can also be done in the form of `var image=document.getElementById('xxx'); image.src="/load_image.php?image_id=1234";` or even with `var image=new Image();`